# Use hidden layers' output to do predictions

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, neural-network

Assuming I have a neural network to predict one target, and I want one of the outputs of my hidden layers to predict another property that is related to my final target. Is there an algorithm to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out TensorFlow Serving’s multi-headed inference feature.